# Change the name of a function used accordingly to a IF/ELSE statement

Tags: php, function, conditional-statements, alias

I am no expert in PHP, so this is something that haunts me for a long time. I can live with it, but if i could find a answer, it could improve my coding a lot! Let's say I have a situation — IF / ELSE — where the same exact cod must be executed, but with different functions inside. Example:

**WHAT I HAVE:**

```
if ($page == 'native') {

// Native page
$title = institutional_settings($id, 'title');
$text = institutional_settings($id, 'text');
$img = institutional_settings($id, 'img');
(... more ... more ... more... )

} else {

// Custom page
$title = personal_settings($id, 'title');
$text = personal_settings($id, 'text');
$img = personal_settings($id, 'img');
(... more ... more ... more... )

}
```

...you see? There is a lot of repeating code.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:**

```
if ($page == 'native') {

// Native page
Here I need to instruct my code to use the "institutional_settings()" function
with an alias, like "the_magic()" function 

} else {

// Custom page
Here I need to instruct my code to use the "personal_settings()" function
with an alias, like "the_magic()" function 

}

// And then, I do not need to repeat the code!
// Here is the magic...
$title = the_magic($id, 'title');
$text = the_magic($id, 'text');
$img = the_magic($id, 'img');
(... more ... more ... more... )
```

I hope I am clear with the idea.
Thank you guys!

G.

Comment: [Variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily store function name as variable and call that function with [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$my_func = $page == 'native' ? 'institutional_settings' : 'personal_settings';

$title = call_user_func_array($my_func, [$id, 'text']);
```

---

Or as mentioned in comments, by [Jeto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965834/jeto), you could call that function as [variable function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
$my_func = $page == 'native' ? 'institutional_settings' : 'personal_settings';    
$title = $my_func($id, 'text');
```

Comment: @Jeto Yes, if you don't mind I will add to the answer

Comment: Oh. It worked like a charm. I was really not aware of this in PHP — $my_func = $var == 'foo' ? 'abc' : 'xyz';